# I think my ssd is bad

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, ssd, mbr

I have a dell laptop that I have been using for a couple years. It had gotten really slow lately. So I bought a new SanDisk ssd plus 120Gb. I took out the old hdd and put in the new ssd. I installed windows 10 and started installing programs. I did a few restarts during this period. Then I decided to reboot again after doing some other things. But got this message saying "windows did not start correctly". I tried doing a lot of things. I finally reinstalled windows and the same thing happened. The first couple of reboots worked fine, then it got this error again. I did the exact same process again with the same results. When windows was running there was no sign of problems. (other than the last time windows programs and things stopped working so I rebooted then got this error). I am not sure what to do. I've tried a lot of things. I think my ssd might be bad. Does anybody have any ideas?

thanks so much.

Dennis

Comment: Nothing in your post would seem to indicate that the SSD is bad - its more likely to be a driver issue under Windows.    I'm a linux person, so not really qualified to answer (hence the comment), but maybe try disabling hibernation ?

Comment: @davidgo Thanks for the comment. I am thinking it may have something to do with a bad windows update. I seem to recall it doing some updates on one of the reoboots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're able to use the drive normally and can do an install, it's unlikely the drive is bad, or just failing when starting Windows.

Initially, try running Startup Repair when you get the "Windows did not start correctly" screen. You can find it by going to **Advanced Options** -> **Startup Repair**

Next, if you want to be methodical, reinstall Windows and start off by not installing any third-party program. Reboot and see if it works. If it does, I would start installing programs one-by-one, rebooting after each install. This will help you determine if there is a program that is breaking your system.

Finally, try installing the [SanDisk SSD Dashboard](https://kb.sandisk.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/15108). This will help you manage the health of your SSD and usually allows you to run S.M.A.R.T on the disk as well. If your SSD does have some hardware problem, there is a good chance this will pick it up. It may also help Windows interface with your drive more efficiently.

Comment: I'd take a look particularly at automatic updates, especially driver updates. They usually install silently and user may not realize when a faulty one is installed.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I am currently thinking the issue was cause by windows update. I turned that off via the service. I am installing one program at a time and will see what happens. thanks!